# 'In this topic' or 'on this topic'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When talking about a topic, which is correct? For example, should I say

> *Selected topics **IN** statistics* or *Selected topics **ON** statistics*

> *Seminar **ON** modern history* or *Seminar **IN** modern history*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "in" and "on" are used with "selected topics" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=selected+topics+in%2Cselected+topics+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cselected%20topics%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cselected%20topics%20on%3B%2Cc0)) and as well with "seminar" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seminar+in%2Cseminar+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseminar%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseminar%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cseminar%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseminar%20on%3B%2Cc0)).

If the topic treats of some part of history "in" should be used because a part is always considered to be *in* the whole and never *on* it. If the topic is not historical but instead is *about* history, as for instance a philosophical discussion of the importance of history, then you should use "on" because this is a usual preposition in that case (with "*about*").

Before you hold a seminar you must decide first what it is going to be *about*; it is a concept similar to "*discussion*" in that respect; you do not say  "a discussion  in  sth" but "a discussion on/about sth"; this can be checked [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20discussion%20in%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en): "in" is not used after "discussion" to introduce the topic of it.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/discussion?q=discussion))
>
> - discussion with somebody (**about** somebody/something)
>   ♦ We had a discussion with them about the differences between Britain and the US.
> - discussion **about** somebody/something A lively discussion followed about whether he should be allowed to join the club.
> - discussion **on** something
>   ♦The pair held informal discussions on a number of topics.
> - discussion **around** something
>   ♦The exhibition offers opportunities for frank discussions around sensitive issues.
> - discussion **of** something
>   ♦ We want to encourage public discussion of mental health issues.

It is therefore more consistent, better, to say "a seminar *on* sth"; however "*in*" is not wrong as quite a number of cases exist where "in" is used to introduce the subject of the seminar (this can be checked [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seminar%20in%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)). Notice in the ngram that "on" is used  more often than "in"; as "in" is used also to introduce the place and the time where is conducted a seminar, the curve for "in" as introducing the subject only is lower than the curve actually shown for this preposition.